# Select a random file from a directory and send it (Python, MIME)

Tags: python, file, random, directory, mime-mail

I am working on a python program that randomly selects a file from a directory and then sends it to you using the `email.mime`module. I am having a problem where I can choose the random file but I can't sent it due to this error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Mihkel\Desktop\dnak.py", line 37, in sendmemeone
    attachment  =open(filename, 'rb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Here is the code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import  MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import os
import random

path ='C:/Users/Mihkel/Desktop/memes'
files = os.listdir(path)
index = random.randrange(0, len(files))
print(files[index])

def send():
    email_user = 'yeetbotmemes@gmail.com'
    email_send = 'miku.rebane@gmail.com'
    subject = 'Test'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To']   = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    body = 'Here is your very own dank meme of the day:'
    msg.attach(MIMEText (body, 'plain'))
    filename=files
    attachment  =open(filename, 'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; 
    filename= "+filename)
    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user,"MY PASSWORD")
    server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
    server.quit()
```

I believe it is just getting the filename as the selected random choice, how could I get it to select the file itself?

EDIT: After making the changes recommended I am now getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Mihkel\Desktop\e8re.py", line 29, in send
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Seems like this part is still taking in the list, how would I fix that?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but the error message is obvious: `open` expects a string which represents a filename including its path. but in your program `filename` is a list of several strings, because of `filename=files` while `files` is the content of a directory: `files = os.listdir(path)` So probably `filename=files[index]` would correct your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select a random file and then throw it away (well, you *print* it, then throw it away):

```
files = os.listdir(path)
index = random.randrange(0, len(files))
print(files[index])
```

(which BTW you can do with `random.choice(files)`)

and when calling `open` you pass it the entire `files` list:

```
filename = files
attachment  = open(filename, 'rb')
```

Instead, pass `open` the file you selected:

```
attachment  = open(random.choice(files), 'rb')
```

**But**, this still wouldn't work since `listdir` only returns the filenames and not the full path, so you will need to get it back, preferably with `os.path.join`:

```
attachment  = open(os.path.join(path, random.choice(files)), 'rb')
```

Comment: Thank you, that last piece of code was what I was looking for. Sorry for the stupid question, I didn't really know what to do after  I wrote the code that  I put in the question

Comment: Actually, I am getting a new error after making the changes, I updated the question

Comment: @Mihkel It is the exact same error. `filename` in your code is still a list! `can only concatenate str (not "list") to str` means one of the 2 is a list. `"attachment; filename= "` is obviously a string, which means `filename` is a list

Comment: Thank you for explaining it, makes it way easier to understand. Sorry for wasting your time and now catching on the first time.